# Java regex unicode support?

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I'm working on an app that receives feedback from customers via email about a particular product.  Currently I'm using java matcher and pattern classes to use regex's to parse certain snippets and keywords.

GIVEN: Customers email us from any email client all over the world (except APAC).

ASK: Do I need to prefix all my my regex's with `\\p{L}` and/or `\\p{M}`  or can I just use
`\\Q<my regex>\\E` (wrap my regex with `\\Q`  and `\\E`)?

Comment: Uhmwait, what does this have to do with Unicode support? `\Q` and `\E`  are here to quote a string literal within a regex (like `Pattern.quote()` as the answer says)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Pattern.quote(yourString);
```

It's the equivalent of `\Q` `\E`

`\Q` ... `\E` is used for literal matching, meaning you would need to know the string to match in advance. For example using, `\Qпривет мир\E` would match:

```
привет мир
```

Although using `\Q.*\E` wouldn't match — it would match:

```
.*
```

So if you're looking to match a string like `привет мир`, or `merhaba dünya` (both) you would want to use something such as `\p{M}*\p{L}+`, which would capture each word (`привет`, `мир`, etc.) or perhaps `\X+` which would capture the whole string `привет мир`.

Comment: thx, however, that seems to work for handling unicode points and marks but it breaks other test cases where meta characters are used.  also "." (period) is treated as a literal instead of it's meta equivalent (especially for multi-line and doitall).

Comment: yeah, the issue is that sometimes I don't know a specific string.  sometimes i want to match a bunch of stuff like ^startjunk.*endjunk:$.  also, there are other unicode surrogates and marks (\uXXXX \uYYY or \uZZZZ) that are getting inserted in between and are breaking some of my regexes.  point being is that I don't know exactly what I can search for to escape as literal.  and like I said a lot of these regexes are using dotall. i can play around with your edited suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Take a look at this example: http://regex101.com/r/gK2kQ4. It might shed some light on how to combine the two.